# How to represent a List of Maps in JSON

Tags: json, dictionary

I'd like to represent a `List<Map<String,List<String>>>` using Json.

Example, i'd like to represent:

- /bin to *.jar and *.war
- /cfg to *.properties and *.data

Could someone confirm that the following is a correct representation?

```
{
  "directories": [
    {
      "name": "bin",
      "regex": [
        "*.jar",
        "*.war"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "cfg",
      "regex": [
        "*.properties",
        "*.data"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Every List is a [] in JSON and every Map is a {} in JSON .. in this case there is an extraneous top-level (should be List/[], not Map/{}) and some elements do not conform to List<String> (e.g. `"name": "bin"`, `"bin"` is a String and not List<String>) .. of course, by removing the Blah<Blah<Blah<..>>> restriction and viewing it in turns of [not-yet-defined-by-class] objects might be simpler.

Comment: You need to decide on your map structure. Do you want it to be Map<String,Object> where Object can be either a String (directory name) or List<String> (regular expressions), or do you want Map<String,List<String>> in which case you must define the directory name value as a list.

Comment: @DarrenNaylor Indeed, i would prefer a `Map<String,Object>`, where `Object` is a `List<String>`. I believe, this is what i built, no?

Comment: A Map<String,List<String>> is different to Map<String,Object> in the sense that the former cannot hold a String value. So your JSON does not represent an object defined using Map<String,List<String>>.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you've resolved this by now but I found this when pursuing a similar question. According to [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) the string you posted is valid as is.